# Bias correction with Qmap

Tags: r

I am trying to process data with a bias correction method using qmap, but I get this message. I would thank your response

```
library ("qmap")

library("readxl")

library("zoo")

library("lattice")

setwd("C:/Users/gen-tya-gradrhi/Desktop/Tesis/Excel")

Milpo <- read_xlsx("Milpo.xlsx", col_names = TRUE)

Milpo <- na.omit(Milpo)

MilpoPISCO <- read_xlsx("Milpo_PISCO.xlsx", col_names = TRUE)

MilpoPISCO <- na.omit(MilpoPISCO)

qm.fit <- fitQmapQUANT(Milpo[,2], MilpoPISCO[,2], qstep=0.1, 
nboot=1, wet.day = TRUE)

qm.a <- doQmapQUANT(MilpoPISCO[,2], qm.fit, type="linear")

qm.s <- doQmapQUANT(MilpoPISCO[,2], qm.fit, type="tricub")

sqrtquant <- function(x, qstep=0.01){
qq <- quantile(x, prob=seq(0, 1, by=qstep))
sqrt(qq)
> }

plot(sqrtquant(MilpoPISCO[,2]), sqrtquant(Milpo[,2]))
```

```
Error in `x[order(x, na.last = na.last, decreasing = decreasing)]`:
! Can't subset columns past the end.
ℹ Locations 19, 23, 25, …, 724, and 213 don't exist.
ℹ There is only 1 column.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
Warning message:
In xtfrm.data.frame(x) : cannot xtfrm data frames
```

I need to solve this problem in order to continue my research

Comment: We don't have access to your C:/ drive, so we don't have access to your test data.  Instead, please post it to your question as the output from `dput()`.  Or `dput(head())` if the data frame(s) is (are) large.

Comment: We can't really help you because your error is not reproducible. At what specific line is it occurring?

Comment: When I want to plot